# Having trouble making boxplots in R

Tags: r, boxplot

I am using the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
Ns <- c(1298, 533, 1342, 897, 774, 254, 812, 324, 1291, 1056, 2172, 516)
p <- (d+1)/2
polls <- map_df(Ns, function(N) {
  x <- sample(c(0,1), size=N, replace=TRUE, prob=c(1-p, p))
  x_hat <- mean(x)
  se_hat <- sqrt(x_hat * (1 - x_hat) / N)
  list(estimate = 2 * x_hat - 1,
       low = 2*(x_hat - 1.96*se_hat) - 1,
       high = 2*(x_hat + 1.96*se_hat) - 1,
       sample_size = N)
}) %>% mutate(poll = seq_along(Ns))
ggplot(data = polls , aes(x = polls$estimate, y = polls$poll)) + geom_boxplot()+
  xlim(-.2,.2) + ylim(1,12)
```

I am getting the following graph:

[image]

But the required graph is as follows:

[image]

Comment: Your code is indeed making a boxplot. Your required graph is not a boxplot, it's a representation of point estimates with error bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may edit some color or range.

```
polls %>%
  mutate(poll = as.factor(poll)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = poll, y = estimate)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = low, ymax = high), width = .2) +
  coord_flip() + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: why was as.factor() used ?

Comment: @MadhavDass I thought it 's factor according to your plot, but if not, you may erase that part.

Comment: how can we add a solid line to 0 and a dashed line in front of it, like shown in the second picture.

Comment: @MadhavDass You may use `geom_abline`